# How do I compute the matrix exponential for a non diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

I am trying to compute the matrix exponential $e^{At}$ for the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 1&0 
\end{pmatrix}$. In this case, I have computed the eigenvalues, which are in $\lambda=0$ with algebraic multiplicity 2, and the generalized eigenvectors are $u_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $u_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$.

how do I proceed now for computing the matrix exponential?

Comment: Hint: We have $A^2=0$, so $\exp(A)=I+A$.

Comment: so, should it be simply $e^{At}=I+At$? And is it a general way of operating? Thanks.

Comment: The general formula for matrices is $\exp(A)=I+A+\frac{1}{2}A^2+\frac{1}{6}A^3\cdots$ as you know.

Comment: sorry if I insist on this topic. I would like to ask if, in the case of a non-diagonalizable matrix, I could instead put it in the Jordan canonical form $J$, and so do somenting like$e^{Jt}$.  The result is different, but would it be correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this precise $A$ is written in the above remarks.

More general, if you know that the set of all generalized eigenvectors still spans the whole space, you can still "pseudo-diagonalize" such a matrix. Hereby, by transforming into a suitable basis, you don't get rid of all off-diagonal entries, but still you can explicitly compute the exponentials. Maybe you want to look up

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: So you mean I could do somehthing like : $e^{At}=Te^{Jt}T^{-1}$ where $J$ is the Jordan canonical form?

Comment: Precisely. Then the exponential preserves the Block structure and you can compute the exponential of a Jordan block.